# trouble in pagination in cordova android using django backend

Tags: python, django, cordova

I am trying to implement the pagenation in phonegap android application.
Up to this line its working fine

```
paginator = Paginator(book1, 2)
```

but I am getting trouble for this line.

```
page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
```

my views.py file is

```
def get_all_book(request):
    if request.method=="GET":
        bk=Book.objects.all().count()
        if bk==0:
            html = render_to_string('book/nobook.html')
            return HttpResponse(html,mimetype="application/text")
        else:
            book1=Book.objects.all()
            paginator = Paginator(book1, 2)
            page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
            try:
                page_obj = paginator.page(page_number)
                print page_obj
                books = paginator.page(page)
            except PageNotAnInteger:

                books = paginator.page(1)
            except EmptyPage:

                books = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

            return render(request, "crave/book/book.html", {'books':books})
```

in html file I am using

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if books.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ books.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ books.number }} of {{ books.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if books.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ books.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

But while I click on next page from mobile app its not passing the next page number to view. i.e page number is not getting automatically incremented.
Some problem with this line

```
<a href="?page={{ books.next_page_number }}">next</a>
```

please help me for this[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
A quiick review of the code reveals mistakes, check again, page_number should be page, most of your checks can be refactored.

from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

def get_all_book(request):
    bk=Book.objects.all()
    if bk.count():
        paginator = Paginator(bk, 2)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            books = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            books = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            books = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        return render(request, "crave/book/book.html", {'books':books})
    else:
        html = render_to_string('book/nobook.html')
        return HttpResponse(html,mimetype="application/text")
```

Comment: getting None for the "print page"
Not able to get the page number. And then need to increment the page number after clicking on next.

Comment: page = request.GET.get('page')
print page
getting None

Comment: Can you debug? if yes, debug the request what does it output?

Comment: I am getting all data in request. What exactly i need to look in to request.
I did print request

Comment: I am using this for phonegap android application. In django application its working fine.

Comment: If it's working in Django, then it's obvious that your mobile application is the problem, debug and you will find the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58683/discussion-between-gaurav-and-petkostas).